# How do I redirect a specific port in the IIS server to an other port

Tags: redirect, iis, web, url-rewriting, port

My URL Rewrite rule only works for port 80 in IIS .

The rewrite works for : http://localhost:80 --> http://localhost:8100

The rewrite works for : http://localhost:80/redirect --> http://localhost:8100

**The rewrite doesnt work for : http://localhost:8080 --> http://localhost:8100**

**The rewrite doesnt work for : http://localhost:8080/redirect --> http://localhost:8100**

My web.config is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to port 8100" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^8100$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:8100/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> The web.config is only working on default http port 80/443 but not for an specific port.

Which changes has to be made in the web.config for working with all ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the variable `{HTTP_HOST}` which already contains the `PORT` information.

To solve this issue you need to adjust two things:

1. Extend the matching pattern within
2. Set the correct address for the redirect

I adjusted your `web.config` to see how it should work with your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to port 8100" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />

                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" >
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
                </conditions>

                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}:8100/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />

            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Because going https://example.com will cause {R:0} to become https://example.com