# Redirect request from port 443 to some other port in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, port

I have created a web site in IIS and hosted a ASP.NET webservice on this site. The requests to the webservice will be send by a 3rd party application to the following URL:

https://www.mywebsite.com/MyWebservice/api/dosomething

When I set the HTTPS binding for my website to default port 443 everything works fine (no certificate problems or anything else).

But because the default port 443 may be blocked by other software I want to move to another port (for example 7443). Changing the calling URL to add the correct port is no option, because the port may be differ from customer to customer (could happen, that we have to move to port 6443 or 8443).

First question:
Do I have to change my HTTPS binding to port 7443 or leave it on port 443? I think I have to change it to port 7443.

Second question:
I installed the module "URL Rewrite" and create a rule in applicationHost.config with the GUI of IIS. But everytime a request comes in I will get an error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I've created an incoming firewall rule to enable port 7443 for incoming traffic, but no success.

My rule in applicationHost.config looks like following:

```
<rewrite>
    <globalRules>
        <rule name="Redirect to port 7443" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="www.mywebsite.com/(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^7443$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.com:7443/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

I found the rule in this question: [How do I redirect a specific port in the IIS server to an other port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040903/how-do-i-redirect-a-specific-port-in-the-iis-server-to-an-other-port)

I also used the rule in the answer to the above question, but without success.

If I enter the blank URL of my website (https://www.mywebsite.com) the browser told me, that the website is not reachable. If I extend the port ((https://www.mywebsite.com:7443) the browser shows by "Hello world" index.html.

Third question: On which level do I have to add the "URL Rewrite" rule (applicationHost.config, web.config of web site or web.config of webservice)? I just want to redirect the requests to my web site / webservice to a different port.

I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Best Regards

Michael

Comment: "because the default port 443 may be blocked by other software" is where you should reveal more information. At the same port 443 you can host many sites/applications, especially on IIS 8 and above with SNI enabled, so there is rarely a need to host your site on a non-standard port.

Comment: Thank you very much Lex for the hint to enable SNI. I'm very new to this stuff, so my thought was, that the port was blocked, but after reading some more information about HTTPS, certificates and bindings I understand, that IIS has a problem choosing the correct certificate for the request, when I have multiple HTTPS bindings to the same port. Is there any solution for IIS 7.x? SNI is not supported for this old versions of IIS.

Comment: On IIS 7.x, you need multiple IP addresses, so that you can set up multiple IP based certificate mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to change my HTTPS binding to port 7443 or leave it on port 443? I think I have to change it to port 7443.

As lex says, we could bind multiple domain to the same 443 port. The IIS will check the domain when the request come to the server, then it will redirect the request to the right application. In my opinion, there is no need to use the new port.

To achieve this, you should add the domain in the IIS site binding's host name textbox.

[image]

> I installed the module "URL Rewrite" and create a rule in applicationHost.config with the GUI of IIS. But everytime a request comes in I will get an error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I've created an incoming firewall rule to enable port 7443 for incoming traffic, but no success.

I found your url rewrite rule match url value is wrong, it will not match anything. The match url part will only match pattern of the url not the domain.

Besides, if you use the site binding, there is no need to add the url rewrite rule.

> On which level do I have to add the "URL Rewrite" rule (applicationHost.config, web.config of web site or web.config of webservice)? I just want to redirect the requests to my web site / webservice to a different port.

In my opinion, you could add the url rewrite rule into the web.config. For example, if you want to redirect the url from 443 port to 7743. You could add the url rewrite rule into the 443's application web.config file.

Comment: Thanks Brando for the explanation. I think Lex' answer to enable SNI (for IIS 8 and above) is the correct solution, because it changes the binding of the certificate from IP:port to hostname:port. You can check this by calling "netsh http show sslcert". If SNI is not enabled, the certificate is bound to 0.0.0.0:443, with SNI enabled it is bound to www.mywebsite.com:443.